# Estimating probability of event given marginal information for discrete random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, parameter-estimation

Given two mutually exclusive events $A$ and $B$ where $\mathbb{P}(X=A)=\alpha$ and $\mathbb{P}(X=B)=\beta\ \ (=1-\alpha)$ suppose we want to estimate $\alpha$. However we are only given samples from $(X,Y)$ (without knowledge of whether $X=A$ or $B$) for the values $C_k$ where the  marginals $C_{A}=Y|X=A$ and $C_B=Y|X=B$  satisfy

$\mathbb{P}(C_A=C_k)=p_k=1/N,$ (uniform) where $k=1,...,N$

$\mathbb{P}(C_B=C_k)=q_k$ for $k=1,...,N.$

Obviously if $q_k$ is close to $p_k$ for all $k$ we cannot estimate $\alpha$ since the later stage samples are identically distributed. But if $q_k$ and $p_k$ differ substantially you should get a good estimate. Is anyone aware of a documented solution for this problem, or feel they can come up with a good estimate?

It should be a well documented problem I expect but I am not that comfortable with sample bias statistics. The probability estimates should depend on the number of samples $m$ and the differences between the probabilities $p_k$ and $q_k$.

P.S. If anyone believes there is need for further clarification, please let me know. I am trying to mathematically interpret the problem of estimating the number of samples from one of two datasets and where each set takes values with different probability compared to each other.

Comment: Your model is unclear.  How are events $A$ and $B$ related?  If they are not related in any way, inference is impossible; but you do not state their relationship.  You also do not specify the relationship between $p_k$ and $q_k$.  You also describe "binomial distribution probabilities" in the title but I see no reference to a binomial distribution in your question.

Comment: $X$ is sampled from a binomial distribution correpsonding to events $A$ and $B$.  $A$ is just uniform distribution, while $B$ is an arbitrary distribution.  I am loosely calling these distributions, but I am really talking about the marginal distributions of $X$. Without $q_k$ differing from $p_k$ you shouldn't be able to make an estimate, so you may assume that $q_k\neq p_k$ for all $k$.

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean.  Events are subsets of the space of elementary outcomes.  They are not themselves random variables nor do they have a distribution.

Comment: See the above comment. I was speaking loosely by calling them distributions, they are just events.

Comment: You need to provide a concrete example of your model; e.g., $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(10, 0.2)$, $A = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7\}$, $B = \{2, 4, 9, 10\}$, from which we can compute $\alpha$ and $\beta$; then $(C \mid X = A) \sim \operatorname{DiscreteUniform}(N)$, $(C \mid X = B) \sim ???$.  Your use of terminology is not consistent with standard statistical practice.

Comment: $X$ is not binomially distributed. It is an arbitrary discrete distribution defined on the events $C_k |A$ and $C_k|B$. There is a two stage sampling process though. The first stage is essentially to sample from $A$ and $B$ which is a choice between two binary events with different probabilities. This is why I used the word "binomial".

Comment: You literally wrote 11 minutes ago that "X is sampled from a binomial distribution."  Now you are saying it is not.  Which one is it?

Comment: I may not have been clear in the comments here but I think the question is well-posed. In other words no assumption is needed on $X$. **Edit**: I meant to use the word Bernoulli I realize now, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128950/discussion-between-asd-and-heropup).

Answer (score 1):

I've thought about this more and if you look in the limit you can recover $\alpha$ exactly of course. The empirical probability you get from samples $r_k:=\mathbb{P}_e(Y=C_k)$ converges to the actual probability $\mathbb{P}(Y=C_k)$ by LLN.

$$\mathbb{P}(Y=C_k)=\mathbb{P}(X=A)\cdot\mathbb{P}(Y=C_k|X=A)+\mathbb{P}(X=B)\cdot\mathbb{P}(Y=C_k|X=B)$$

$$\mathbb{P}(Y=C_k)=\alpha/N+(1-\alpha)q_k$$

So if you look at the estimate $r_k\sim\alpha/N+(1-\alpha)q_k$ and solve for $\alpha$ you should get a good estimate:

$$\alpha\sim \frac{r_k-q_k}{\frac{1}{N}-q_k}.$$
The probability that $\alpha$ differs from this depends on the convergence behavior for LLN with discrete random variables $(X,Y)$. I guess this kinda thing is well-known by people, but I've forgotten what the optimal bounds are here.

Comment: This last equation holding for all $k$  makes me wonder if you can actually solve for the $q_k$ without information about them (in the limit) if you have all of the $r_k$.